# Using html2text and clean some text in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, selenium

I'm using `Html2Text` to convert html code into a text.
Works very well, but I can't find many examples or documentation on the internet.

I'm reading users name in this way:

```
text_to_gain = hxs.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"yq-question-detail-profile-img")]/a/img/@alt').extract()
if text_to_gain:
        h = html2text.HTML2Text()
        h.ignore_links = True
        item['author'] = h.handle(text_to_gain[0])
else:
        item['author'] = "anonymous"
```

But my output is this :

```
u'Duncan\n\n'
```

It's useful have the \n when i read long text or message, but for single string or some one i want to keep only the name.

```
'Duncan'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) function. This will remove all the whitespaces.

```
>>> a = u'Duncan\n\n'
>>> a
u'Duncan\n\n'
>>> a.strip()
u'Duncan'
>>> str(a.strip())
'Duncan'
```

Comment: and for u' ?

Is strange that html2text not use any function to not keep the \n

Comment: The `u` just indicates that the string is in Unicode character encoding. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings).

Comment: You can use `str()` function for that. You can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855663/2932244).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this too, just remove the character '\n':

```
>>> st = 'Duncan\n\n'
>>> st.replace('\n', '')
'Duncan'
>>>
```